Clarification on Lookup Tables
I'm looking at this transaction, which is a Jupiter swap:
curl https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '
  {
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "method": "getTransaction",
    "params": [
      "urhum9M5moCkRHcmEEs7cXAg1W8TzLtbNosJjrLGPaLSxUGzVQgqoAHxv2ZuCbcoZzzrGxCkUEhCrwUDvy9e2Fp",
      {"encoding":"json", "maxSupportedTransactionVersion" :0}
    ]
  }
'

In the meta field, I can see the inner instructions. The first inner instruction has programIndex 17:
"innerInstructions": [
        {
          "index": 1,
          "instructions": [
            {
              "accounts": [
                16,
                13,
                0,
                1,
                2,
                9,
                12,
                10,
                11,
                15,
                18,
                18,
                19
              ],
              "data": "PgQWtn8ozixJFWQTBd2uwJWAkFJKp92d5",
              "programIdIndex": 17,
              "stackHeight": 2
            },
...

According to Solscan, the first inner instruction is a call to Lifinity Swap V2 (2wT8Yq49kHgDzXuPxZSaeLaH1qbmGXtEyPy64bL7aD3c):
https://solscan.io/tx/urhum9M5moCkRHcmEEs7cXAg1W8TzLtbNosJjrLGPaLSxUGzVQgqoAHxv2ZuCbcoZzzrGxCkUEhCrwUDvy9e2Fp
Now, this transaction has a lookup table with address: FgvF27Dnw7Ciy6w6QMfk8oKh2duSWUtK9ssUYhFccr6r. I would expect that the entry at index 17 is the same Lifinity Swap V2 address, however it is not. In this table, the address 2wT8Yq49kHgDzXuPxZSaeLaH1qbmGXtEyPy64bL7aD3c is actually at index 80. In the transaction, I don't see anywhere the index 80 being used.
What am I missing?
Also, how do I know which indexes are referring to the account keys and which to the lookup tables?

That index is after the lookup table accounts are pulled in, ordered by write access and then read access accounts and appended to the accounts included in the transaction, as shown here in the solana explorer. (note, they display indexes starting from 1 instead of 0.)
Lookup tables and the corresponding account indexes are serialized at the end of versioned transactions like so:

number of tables

table address
number of write accounts
table account indexes
number of read accounts
table account indexes (The index 80 you are looking for would be in here)



... repeat if multiple tables
